# Python - loading module from directory

Tags: python

Why python load my module from directory, even if the directory shouldn't be treated as a package (doesn't contains `__init__.py`)?

```
app
  main.py
  fake_module
    module.py
```

this works, even if `fake_module` doesn't contains `__init__.py`

```
import fake_module.module
```

If i would create regular `fake_module` with `__init__.py` and `module.py` file somewhere in `sys.path`, will be `module.py` loaded from this regular `fake_module` package?

I am using pycharm and python3.3

Comment: Are you 100% certain that you are looking at the **right** fake_module? What does `print fake_module.module.__file__` give you?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it gives that app/fake_module/module.py

Comment: @JBernardo: no i didn't

Comment: @Krab: and `print fake_module.__file__` prints what?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it throws exception AttributeError: 'fake_module' object has no attribute '__file__'

Comment: @Krab: What does `print type(fake_module)` give?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: <class 'module'>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like [the `__init__.py` is optional](http://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#pep-420-implicit-namespace-packages) as of Python 3.3. See also [PEP420](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/).

Comment: Bingo, I forgot about the new implicit namespaces support in 3.3.